# Hibernate - different values of two fields mapped the same column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two fields mapped the same column:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "database_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Database database;

@Column(name = "database_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private long databaseId;
```

And when I read entity object from db: `entityManager.find(entityClass, id);`
Sometimes `entity.getDatabase().getId()` has correct value, but `entity.getDatabaseId() = 0;`And I can't resolve why it's happen.

So, what is the reason of this strange behavior may be?

Answer (score 2):

You should not keep `databaseId` in your entity, that's not correct.
You have correct mapping.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "database_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Database database;
```

Now, if you want to get database id value, you can just use `entity.getDatabase().getId()` end this statement **won't perform any additional sql query, even if you use Lazy loading.**

You can also use database id in queries.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.database.id = :id");
```

**This query doesn't perform any joins.**

Comment: Exactly, the equivalent of database a foreign-key is an Entity reference in JPA, you should never manage them as basic columns.